# How to best overload operator < > <= >= but only write one or two comparison functions?

Tags: c++, comparison, operator-overloading

I have a class with an attribute of type std::string. I'd like to provide some comparison operator functions like <, >, ==, <=, and >= for the class by comparing the attribute.

My questions is that: any easy way or tool to

(1) just write one or two functions, such as the one for operator < (and ==), others can be automatically generated.

(2) or even simpler since the class comparison is depending on its attribute of type `std::string` whose comparison functions are already provided.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Curiously recurring template pattern

In this case you provide a simple base class which implements all needed operators and simply inherit from it:

```
template <class T>
struct implement_relational_operators{
    friend bool operator<=(const T & a,const T & b){ return a < b || a == b; }
    friend bool operator>(const T &  a, const T & b){ return !(a <= b); }
    friend bool operator!=(const T &  a, const T & b){ return !(a == b);}
    friend bool operator>=(const T &  a, const T & b){ return !(a < b); }
};

template <class T>
struct scalar : public implement_relational_operators<scalar<T> >{
    T value;
    bool operator<(const scalar& o) const { return value < o.value;}
    bool operator==(const scalar& o) const { return value == o.value;}
};
```

This doesn't share the drawbacks from `std::rel_ops` (see below). However, you still need to implement `operator<` and `operator==`. A similar trick is used by [`boost`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/operators.hpp).

C++20's `<=>` might improve the situation further (see below).

## `std::rel_ops` (deprecated in C++20)

`std::rel_ops` provides the additional operations based on `<` an `==`, so you just need to write two operators.

However, it will be deprecated in C++20, where [`a <=> b`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0768r1.pdf) will get thrown into the mix.

### Requirements

You just need the equality (`operator=`) and the lesser than (`operator<`) comparison operator. The rest can be generated automatically with [`std::rel_ops`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp), since the following holds:

```
a != b equal to !(a == b)
a <= b equal to (a < b) || (a == b)
a >= b equal to !(a < b)
a >  b equal to !(a <= b)
```

Note that these are less efficient than writing those by hand.

### Warning

However, since it's easy to provide those operators yourself you should just take the extra effort and write them. And they also have some drawbacks, as mentioned by [R. Martinho Fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917848/how-to-best-overload-operator-but-only-write-one-or-two-comparison-fun#comment19184363_13917897):

> Note that [they] won't work properly unless you:
>
> 1. add `using namespace std::rel_ops` on every context you use the operators; or
> 2. add `using::operator!=; using::operator<=; using::operator>=; using::operator>;` in the namespace of your class (`using namespace std::rel_ops` in the namespace of your class is not acceptable because it does not get picked up by ADL).

Comment: If you have only `<=` then `A == B` is identical to `A <= B && B <= A`.

Comment: @Dialecticus: While this is true (and `<` is simply `A <= B && !(B <= A)`, `rel_ops` uses the given operators.

Comment: Note that this won't work properly unless you: 1) add `using namespace std::rel_ops` on every context you use the operators (which is not really nice); or 2) add `using::operator!=; using::operator<=; using::operator>=; using::operator>;` in the namespace of your class (`using namespace std::rel_ops` in the namespace of your class is not acceptable because it does not get picked up by ADL).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, is this the reason std::rel_ops are going to be deprecated in C++20? (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp)

Comment: @alfC see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r2.pdf (design of `<=>`) and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0768r1.pdf (library proposal) for the reasons. For `rel_ops`, you need two functions, whereas P0512 describes a new `<=>` operator that handles all cases at once and can be used for the other operators that have been provided by `rel_ops` so far. `rel_ops` will be therefore deprecated due to a better alternative. I'll update my answer later today.

Comment: Until then, the most elegant alternative is to use boost.operators https://stackoverflow.com/a/48315069/225186

Comment: Why implement `operator<=` with two comparisons?  Could one not simply `return !(b<a)`?

Answer (score 11):

You could use `std::rel_ops`, but it would be wrong. That's a sledgehammer that doesn't belong in anyone's toolkit.

The usual approach is to define `operator==` and `operator<` with knowledge of the details of the class. The remaining four operators can be written with those:

`a != b` is `!(a == b)`

`a <= b` is `!(b < a)`

`a > b` is `b < a`

`a >= b` is `!(a < b)`

Comment: Actually, even `==` can be written in terms of `<` as an equivalence test: `!(a < b && b < a)` and `!=` as `!(a != b)`

Comment: @Casey - the point of this pattern is to be able to write `!=` in terms of `==` and, when inequalities are also needed, to be able to write the various inequalities in terms of `<`. In some cases there is no meaningful `<` (complex numbers, for example), and in those cases writing `==` in terms of `<` doesn't work. Writing the inequalities with a single comparison and possibly a negation is more efficient than using `||` or `&&`. I've re-checked the code, and as far as I can see, it's correct. If you still think it's wrong, provide an example.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I hit "add" before I realized you had swapped the arguments. There's nothing wrong with the comparisons you've made.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use CRTP such as in Barton Nackman trick:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton%E2%80%93Nackman_trick

```
// A class template to express an equality comparison interface.
template<typename T> class equal_comparable {
    friend bool operator==(T const &a, T const &b) { return  a.equal_to(b); }
    friend bool operator!=(T const &a, T const &b) { return !a.equal_to(b); }
};

class value_type
 // Class value_type wants to have == and !=, so it derives from
 // equal_comparable with itself as argument (which is the CRTP).
 : private equal_comparable<value_type> {
  public:
    bool equal_to(value_type const& rhs) const; // to be defined
};
```

Answer (score 2):

(If you have control over the class) the correct way to do this is by using Boost.Operators http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/utility/operators.htm

```
#include<cassert>
#include<boost/operators.hpp>

struct A : boost::totally_ordered<A> // implies equality-comparable and less-than-comparable
{
    int val_;
    A(int const& v) : val_{v}{}
    bool operator==(A const& other) const{return other.val_ == val_;}
    bool operator<(A const& other) const{return other.val_ < val_;}
};

int main(){
    A a1{5};
    A a2{7};

    assert(!(a1 == a2)); // user defined operator==
    assert(a1 != a2);    // automatically defined !=
    assert(a1 < a2);     // user defined operator<
    assert(a2 > a1);     // automatically defined >
    assert(a2 >= a1);    // automatically defined >=
    assert(a1 <= a2);    // automatically defined <=
}
```

Boost.Operators uses CRTP (see other answers), but does everything for you.

I just learnt from the other answers about `std::rel_ops`, however my premature conclusion is that it is not very useful.
Boost.Operators seems to be more powerful and customizable, although it is a bit intrusive.

Note that you have to *know* which of the operations to implement (in this case `operator==` and `operator<`. But in *principle* you could just define `operator!=` and `operator>`. 
It would be cool for the other operators to be automatically "deduced", see [Very automatic operator generator in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156577/very-automatic-operator-generator-in-c)

---

This is another example, where only one operator is enough. (But probably inefficient?)

```
#include<boost/operators.hpp>

struct A : boost::totally_ordered<A>, boost::equivalent<A>{
    int val_;
    A(int const& v) : val_{v}{}
    bool operator<(A const& other) const{return other.val_ < val_;}
};
```