# Very automatic operator generator in C++

Tags: c++11, operators, sfinae, regular-type

C++ has a nice idiom that allows one to write classes that automatically fulfill certain relations between operators. For example this allows to define `operator==` and not bother to defined `operator!=` as well. This is the idea behind Boost.Operators.

This is an example:

```
template<class Self> // this class is defined only once
struct equally_comparable{
    friend bool operator!=(Self const& s1, Self const& s2){return !(s1==s2);}
};
```

This class can used repeatedly to enforce consistent logic between `==` and `!=` (and avoid errors)

```
struct A : equally_comparable<A>{ // 
    int value;
    A(int v) : value(v){}
    friend bool operator==(A const& a1, A const& a2){return a1.value == a2.value;}
};

int main(){

    A a1{4};
    A a2{4};
    assert(a1 == a2);
    A a3{5};
    assert(a1 != a3); // uses automatically generated operator !=
}
```

Now, I want to go one level further and have a class similar to `equally_comparable` and define the *other* function. For example if `operator==` is defined then define `operator!=` (like above), but also viceversa.

The first naive attempt works

```
template<class Self>
struct equally_comparable{
    friend bool operator!=(Self const& s1, Self const& s2){return !(s1==s2);}
    friend bool operator==(Self const& s1, Self const& s2){return !(s1!=s2);}
};
```

because only one of the two functions need to be defined in `struct A` (either `operator==` or `operator!=`). However it is dangerous because if one forget to define either operator in `A` there is an infinite recursion (and a runtime segfault). It also looks fragile.

**Is is possible to improve over this and detect that at least one is defined in the derived class at compile time? or more generally is there a generic way to have a class that generates the missing operators?** (i.e. a step beyond Boost.Operators).

Comment: does it have to be a member function (equally comparable)?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea generally. If you have functions easily derivable from each other, it is almost always a good idea to pick one (e.g. `operator==`) and _force_ classes implement this and not the other. Otherwise this would lead to confusion and inconcistency.

Comment: @doublep if performance is a concern: it might be cheaper to implement `!=` and derive `==` from `!=` than the other way round.

Comment: @Alex, being member can disambiguate the implementation but it forces the use to define member functions. So, yes, if that helps to implement this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I would use SFINAE in order to check for comparators at compile time and choose them accordingly.

so this would work as follows:

- create a tagging class (empty) here in the example it is called `equal_comparable_tag`
- classes you want to exploit the additional overloads should be derived from this tag (since it is inherited the tag doesn't incur a size penalty).
- the additional comparator functions have an `enable_if` guard because of function matching the non templated version is preferred. The guard checks if the class is derived from the tagging class.

### working example

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct equal_comparable_tag {};

struct tmp : public equal_comparable_tag {
    friend bool operator==(const tmp &, const tmp &) {
        std::cout << "baz";
        return false;
    }
};

struct tmp2 : public equal_comparable_tag {
    friend bool operator!=(const tmp2 &, const tmp2 &) {
        std::cout << "baz";
        return false;
    }
};

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
std::is_base_of<equal_comparable_tag, T>::value,
bool
>::type
operator!=(const T &, const T&) {
    std::cout << "foo";
    return true;
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
std::is_base_of<equal_comparable_tag, T>::value,
bool
>::type
operator==(const T &, const T&) {
    std::cout << "bar";
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    tmp a,b;
    tmp2 c,d;

    if (a != b) {} // foo
    if (a == b) {} // baz
    if (c != d) {} // baz
    if (c == d) {} // bar
}
```

### Notes

Be aware, that automatic function signature checking can also be done (usually through type traits and function pointers See [this article](http://www.gockelhut.com/c++/articles/has_member)), but is considerable more complicated. This is required if you want to check if two functions are implemented. Be also aware that you need to check all possible combinations.

i.e.: if you have `operator >` and `operator ==` you'd have to check:

- has member function > and member function ==
- has free function > and has free function ==
- has free function > and member function ==
- hash member function > and free function ==

and these checks fail if somebody uses implicit conversions e.g.:

```
struct tmp4 {
    tmp4(int) {
    }
    tmp4() {}
    operator int() const {
        return 10;
    }
    bool operator!=(int) const {
        std::cout << "baz";
        return false;
    }
};  
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    tmp4 g, h;
    if (g != h) {} // compiles!
}
```

Comment: c++14 allows you to use `enable_if_t` which looks a bit prettier. and there are also other versions of `enable_if` which could be applied here.